# Decimal exponents

Tags: algorithms, mathematical-programming

I've written a library which stores numbers as an array of nibbles.  You set the digits and decimal places at compile time.
I've written all basic math +-*/% but I'm not sure how to do exponentiation ($a^b$). Raising a decimal to an integer power is a piece of cake, but how do you do, e.g., $4.6345^{3.1425}$ from first principles?

Comment: @DavidRicherby yes it is. Ihad to retype and post again. The android-app said it had failed to load question. And I couldn't see it in newest questions

Comment: Don't trust the app; I recommend to use a browser.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Stoopid computers. :-)